# Create custom domain with mongoDB atlas using CNAME record

Tags: mongodb, amazon-route53, cname, mongodb-atlas

I am setting up a mongoDB cluster on mongoDB atlas.

To connect to the cluster you get an URL like `cluster-01.mongodb.net`. For convenience reasons I tried to set up a CNAME record on AWS Route53 pointing from `cluster-01.my-company.co` to the mongoDB cloud URL above.

When connecting to the cluster:

`mongo "mongodb+srv://mongo-01.my-company.co/test" --username user`

But I am getting the following error:

`DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "_mongodb._tcp.mongo-01.my-company.co": Undefined error: 0`

Has anyone experiences in setting up a CNAME record for a mongoDB cloud cluster?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Magnus, unfortunately not. I did not get involved deeper. I use the domain from mongodb now. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.  See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-2556 and in particular this commit https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/commit/3c1ff124ce47fa7b5d97b336028e575efd0e3d1e , which specifically disallows using CNAME with mongo+srv.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, mongo atlas doesn't have such feature. If your requirement is to update your cluster name and if it is okay to have a little downtime, Use mongo atlas live migration service to migrate it to a different cluster(with the new name) using the following link, cutover to stop migration once migration is done and use new cluster.

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/live-import/

In case, if you want to have this feature in upcoming releases of mongo atlas, There is a request for this feature in the mongo feedback portal.
https://feedback.mongodb.com/forums/924145-atlas/suggestions/40474783-allow-custom-dns-hostnames-to-be-added-to-cluster

Also, this live migration service supports upgrading the mongo cluster version in atlas with minimal downtime.

Comment: Thanks Pavan! My requirement was rahter having the mongo cluster reachable via a 3rd level domain of my companies domain.